# FedEx error: Special service invalid 8201

Tags: label, fedex, reply

I'm trying to connect to FedEx WebServices API for OpenShip Service.

I'm using WSDL of v9.

Below is the reply when I try to process a request:

```
     <v9:Notifications>
        <v9:Severity>ERROR</v9:Severity>
        <v9:Source>ship</v9:Source>
        <v9:Code>8201</v9:Code>
        <v9:Message>Service is invalid</v9:Message>
        <v9:LocalizedMessage>Service is invalid</v9:LocalizedMessage>
     </v9:Notifications>
```

Can anyone please let me know which element/attribute the error is referring to?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are passing a valid ServiceType.